# What does 妄想ダダもれ mean?

Tags: translation

Found this word here. https://gigazine.net/news/20110530_how_words_are_formed_in_the_brain/

> 脳内**妄想ダダ漏れ**の危機か、思考を読み取る手がかりが解明される

I've looked it up and came up with "妄想" meaning "delusion" and "漏れ" meaning "leakage". I'm lost on what ダダ means here.

I tried looking for other examples and found this on twitter:
https://twitter.com/storyer0519/status/949526914934349824

> **妄想ダダ漏れ**の下書き。

Comment: https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A0%E6%BC%8F%E3%82%8C

Comment: so in the 2nd line it's "rough draft of big leakage of a wild idea"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

だだ is a relatively rare prefix that works as an intensifier.

> #### [だだ](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A0-560648)
>
> ［接頭］名詞・動詞・形容詞などに付いて、程度がはなはだしい、めちゃくちゃであるなどの意を表す。「だだ黒い」「だだ漏れ」

So basically it's something like "super-", but this is used only with a few words, and it is no longer productive. だだ黒い is almost obsolete now, and perhaps だだ漏れ and だだ下がり (as in テンションだだ下がり "to be completely turned off") are the only words that are commonly in use today. You may think of them as distinct no-adjectives.

妄想ダダ漏れの下書き means "a draft that doesn't hide my fantasy at all".